# Getting Started Using ROS on a Micro Controller

Tags: ros, microcontroller, rosserial, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm relatively new with Robotics as I've previously only done things with Parallax's robot kits.  I'd like to start learning ROS but there doesn't seem to be any starting help.  To begin with I need to get a computer with Ubuntu as the Windows version is limited.  The bigger question is, what MicroController do I need?  I was under the assumption when I used the Parallax Basic-Stamp 2 that my desktop software that I programmed with translated my program into something the chip understands.  But is this universal?  Can I pick pretty much any microcontroller in the world to use with the ROS system?  Please help guys as I'm completely lost.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10805/getting-started-using-ros-on-a-micro-controller/) by [Hannibal](https://answers.ros.org/users/922/hannibal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is not about micro controller programming in the first place. It is a set of tools, libraries and modules to work with robots. The PR2 and most other robots run normal Linux PCs. Have a look at the [getting started page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/StartGuide) for more information.

There are some packages to work with micro controllers though, for instance [rosserial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to work with embedded systems (but rather more powerful systems than Stamp) you can also have a look at [EROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros).

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

anyone else sick of just being redirected to the getting started pages and tutorials?

---

Originally posted by [Jayl](https://answers.ros.org/users/12376/jayl/) with karma: 31 on 2014-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-01**:
What would you do instead?

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-26**:
The person is usually here not because he is too ignorant. But, in most cases, because he has gone through the tutorials and has understood nothing. To me the tutorials were pellucid. May not be the same to others.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-26**:
@Jayl, ROS is tough to people who aren't already computer science students/graduates. If you are not already familiar with c++, cmake, makefiles, unix, a few operating system concepts, etc, you are sure to get frustrated. The only way is the hard way, learn it all by yourself.